# Google Drive with FUSE

Tags: unix, fuse, google-drive-api

Would be possible to use Google Drive with FUSE for to build filesystem in unix systems?

Comment: Since this question is ranked highest on google and lists the derelict "fuse-google-drive" project, here's todays most up to date fuse implementation for google drive: https://github.com/astrada/google-drive-ocamlfuse

Comment: Ubuntu guide for the impatient: http://www.ubuntugeek.com/how-to-mount-google-drive-in-ubuntu-linux-using-google-drive-ocamlfuse.html

Answer (score 10, accepted):

https://github.com/jcline/fuse-google-drive

> fuse-google-drive is a fuse filesystem wrapper for Google Drive released under GPLv2
>
> Currently in alpha stages. Do not trust this for anything important...
>
> Discussion:
>
> - #fuse-google-drive on irc.freenode.net
>
> Usage:
>
> Right now you need to go to http://code.google.com/apis/console and create a new app and generate a client id and client secret for an install application. The clientid value and clientsecrets value should each go into:
>
> ```
> $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fuse-google-drive/clientid
> $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fuse-google-drive/clientsecrets
> ```
>
> respectively. You should `chmod 700 $XDG_CONFIG_HOME/fuse-google-drive` as well. If the folder does not exist at runtime, a helpful message is printed and the directory is created with the correct permissions if possible. Note: If `$XDG_CONFIG_HOME` is unset on your system, it defaults to `~/.config/`.
>
> ```
> $ mkdir mountpoint
> $ ./fuse-google-drive mountpoint
> ```

Answer (score 9):

You can use the [Google Documents List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/) to create a Fuse client.