# Integrate other filesystems into google drive?

Tags: web-services, filesystems, google-drive-api

Now that Google Drive has launched I wondered if it is possible to integrate other filesystems directly into it. I think about something like a FUSE or DOKAN for Google Drive. While Google Drive would be the Root Filesystem, others could be integrated in form of a folder.

For example, one could mount DropBox into Google Drive and then access his DropBox files right through any Google Drive client.

Get the idea?

This would also allow the people to use storage of their own servers & add it to Google Drive. This would make it more private & secure while they can benefit from all advantages provided by Google Drive.

Do you know if creating something like that is possible through the Google Drive API?
If not, how likely is it that such a functionality will be added in the future?

Google Drive, or any other web storage service that implements this feature first could become THE WEB FILESYSTEM. All webservices would only have to support one such service, while the support for all other filesystems is achieved by such filesystem extensions.

This would be the future of the web.

Comment: Check this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10306252/google-drive-with-fuse

Comment: @ClaudioCherubino no, I don't want to integrate Google Drive into the local filesystem. I want to integrate other filesystems into Google Drive (including maybe my own local filesystem)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm reading through some of your comments on the answers, as well as your original post. I'm not sure if we're on the same page about what a "file system" is. (I'm not sure I know what it is for sure, but I'll try to lay out a few things, and other people can correct me.)

A file system may have:

1. some binary data, files, directory structures, etc.
2. some meta-data, such as indexes on 1. above
3. Additionally we might want to include in the broader definition: some computational logic (a specification (spec) and a "driver" that implements the spec) which tells a computer what the rules are, for reading/writing data to 1. and 2..

If we regard Gdrive as a file system, the driver spec is Google's List API documentation, and any app that implements that documentation is essentially a "Gdrive driver" ; likewise, if we regard Dropbox as a file system, the driver spec is the Dropbox API documentation, and any app that implements that documentation is a "Dropbox driver".

Now I'm going to ask, where do you plan to implement your drivers? You and I certainly can't implement a Dropbox driver on the Gdrive server cluster - I don't think Google will let us do that yet (though perhaps they will one day). So seeing your Dropbox folder mounted as a folder in your Gdrive "on the cloud", which is what you view in the standard https://drive.google.com user-interface isn't going to happen anytime soon. (Nor is seeing your Gdrive mounted in your Dropbox folder "on the cloud" on the latter's website.)

*However*, you certainly can implement both the Dropbox and Gdrive drivers on your personal computing client devices (desktop / notebook / phone / tablet / etc.). So your client can access both Dropbox's and Gdrive's "cloud" storage, and sync data from each of those, to the same folder **on your client's disk drive**. (I'm almost certain that they've issued advice that doing this will result in "undefined" behavior, but you can give it a shot.)

Answer (score 3):

It is definitely possible in theory to write a tool that would keep in sync a Drive folder with another storage system.

The current Google Drive sync clients provided by Google are in this category:

```
Google Drive root folder <-> local file folder
```

Similarly anyone could write a sync tool for any combination of:

- Google Drive folder
- Dropbox
- Fuse
- ...

I would simply use the [Google Document List API](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/) to do this for now. It has a really nice [Change feed](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/#detecting_changes_to_resources) useful for polling.

Comment: I was not talking about syncing. I want to directly integrate a filesystem INTO GOOGLE DRIVE, not the other way around.

Comment: If I understand correctly you mean that the sync logic + configuration should basically be hosted on Drive's server I highly doubt that the Drive team will be working on this soon (or ever) :) Time could prove me wrong of course though your best bet is 3rd party implementing sync logics between the two systems imo.

Comment: No, there is no sync logic. Again: I want to directly integrate a filesystem into google drive. So when for example someone requests file /files/dropbox/path/to/my/file.txt, google drive would recognize that this path points to a file that is in another filesystem and pass the request to it. The filesystem would the request the dropbox file /path/to/my/file.txt and return it to google drive, wich responds the file gotten from the filesystem.